# PHP PDO, Return value object after insert query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried to search an answer to this question but I couldn't really find it. I have a new value object that is partially filled which I want to insert into the database.

When the insert was succesfull I want to return the value object again back to the client side (a Flex application in my case). The reason I want this is to have the auto increment value for the id of the value object.

I thought I could use the fetchAll method again, but apparently that gives a general error incase of update/insert queries. So what is the correct way to return an updated value object back?

Kind regards,
Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want get only ID inserted query, you can use lastInsertId() function of PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the answer. I should have been able to find that ..... still thanks :)

Comment: And what if I need not only ID, but some other fields which are filled during inserting? I.e. "insert_date" with default `NOW()` in mysql?

Answer (score -1):

for last insert id

```
    $this->conn->lastInsertId();
```

NOTE :: $this->conn : your PDO db connection

for number of rowcounts :

```
    return $this->insqry->rowCount();
```

NOTe :: $this->insqry : use for preparing query